# Mysql bigger than problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id > '$id' LIMIT 1")
```

To get the element whose id is bigger than and closest to our current $id.But I could not do this.What should i do or what is my error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this!

```
"SELECT * FROM images WHERE id > '$id' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what you have now I think your query should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM images WHERE id > '$id' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: is it correct to put quotes around $id. I mean it's not integer, is it?